# IDM started downloading again after power cut

Tags: windows-10

A 40gb was downloaded completely but it was at the stage of merging all downloaded files into one folder but during that process power went out. When I opened the pc again and started downloading again, it started from 5gb. All progress was lost. But in my drive I can see the zip file of 40gb which cant be opened. Can this problem be fixed or I just have to download this again?

Comment: You have answered your own question. Ifyou cant open it then its corrupted

Comment: ... therefore it has to download it again.

Comment: @ChanganAuto cant I repair the zip file which would give me some data which is not corrupted and continue the download from there? Its just so much frustrating to download it all again tbh.

Comment: It's not a matter of "fixing" the zip file, but of completing its missing parts. IDM is normally restartable, so it's strange that it's starting again from zero.

Comment: What is your question? If IDM doesn’t restart the merge process then you are out of luck. It likely was partially do the operation in memory and only completed part of it. There is no way to fix the corruption with the file.